# download using API

Tags: python, dataframe, download, extract

I created a DASH web app with the intention of extracting certain requests using the Siconfi API, but when I download the data, the file comes up empty, with no data at all. I'm not sure if it's a problem with the backend-front-end relationship or if there's some incorrect function. I need help!"

I expected that when I performed the download, the data would be returned to me in the downloaded file."